# How can i add "essential typing" use with UIAlertController's textField in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I want to add function such as, if there are no any letters in `textfield` and press confirm button, than `textfield` print `"you must need to write folder name"`, and stop action while there print is showing. I was find something examples in google, but I don't know how adjust with my code.

```js
func folderAddAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Folder name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField {(folderAddTF) in folderAddTF.placeholder = "Please add folder name"
        print("+ clicked." )
    }
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default){ (_) in
        guard let folder = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        
        print("folderName: \(folder)")
        self.folderNames.append(folder)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are in the right way, but in here you need check the textfield is empty or not on your validation on user press the Confirm button like this

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default){ (_) in
            guard let folder = alert.textFields?.first?.text, !folder.isEmpty else {
             self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                if let getPlaceholder = alert.textFields?.first, let placeHolderText = getPlaceholder.placeholder{
                    getPlaceholder.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderText,
                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
                }
                return }
            print("folderName: \(folder)")
        }
```

Comment: I really appreciate you that makes me help!